# How to make the needed text to appear word after word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that appends a text into the `div` with some color effect.
I want to make the text appearing word after word. (But I need this effect only on the text of second function's parameter "str", the "who" have to appear normal.
I found an example code of the effect that I need, but I don't get how to make both functions work together as I want.

JS:

```
// my function
    var showText = function(who, str) {
      if(str !== "") {
        $("#storyBoard").append("<p><span style='color:#323232;'>" + who.name + ": " + "</span>" + str + "</p>");
      };
    };

showText(somObj, "The text i want to append on the page when calling the function");

    // the function i want to add into my first function
    $(function() {
      var a = new String;
      a = $('.text_cont_inner').text();
      $('.text_cont_inner').text('');
      var c = a.length;
      j = 0;
      setInterval(function() {
        if(j < c) {
          $('.text_cont_inner').text($('.text_cont_inner').text() + a[j]);
          j = j + 1;
        } else {
          $('.text_cont_inner').removeClass('after')
        }
      }, 100);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>MacroG0D - My first game</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ='Js/main.js' type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "storyBoard">
<h1> Star Wars - Healing <br>The Breach:<hr></h1>

<p class="intro">A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away</p>
<p> Welcome to the virtual pseudo-reality. Are you ready to start this journey? </p>
</div>
<input type="text" id ="myInput" placeholder="Type the command here" name="myInput" autofocus autocomplete='off'/>
<button id="btn" type="submit"> Enter </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Snippets are only for runnable code. if your code consists only of JavaScript, avoid using them.

Comment: I added my html code and also the 'showText' function call to show what exactly i mean in my question.

Comment: I've made some short example. I hope this is what you want :).
https://jsfiddle.net/b9fvae7o/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
var showText = function(who, str) {
  if(!str){
    return;
  }

  var textNode = $("#storyBoard") // take container
    .append("<p><span style='color:#323232;'>" + who.name + ": </span><span></span></p>") // add contents
    .find("p span:last-сhild")[0]; // select last <span> to put str value into

  var words = str.split(" "); // break a string on words
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() { // set new interval and remember it's ID
    if (!words.length) { // no words left in array
      return clearInterval(intervalId); // stop running interval and exit
    }

    textNode.innerText += " " + words.shift(); // add space and next word
  }, 100); // milliseconds between word insertions
};
```

Comment: Got this error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: lastChild

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but it still doesn't work. Maybe i didn't explain my question well.. I dont know how to explain better then just show: http://macrogaming.usite.pro/index.html
For example, when the user puts 'yes' in the command line, the text "Wellcome aboard", and so on have to appear word after word. (but "The machine", have to appear normaly).